# Manually setting the Google Analytics Client ID

Tags: google-analytics

I have a sub-domain that I am unable to put GTM or GA tracking code on.  I have GA on the main domain.

I can retrieve the _ga cookie and get the Client ID but but if a user has not been to the main website they won't have one.

My question is:

Can I set a cookie called _ga (in the same format as GA sets it) and will this get picked up by GA if the user then goes back to the main website?

Answer (score 0):

This article seems to be what you need:

**Cookie Settings And Subdomain Tracking In Universal Analytics**
https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/cookie-settings-and-subdomain-tracking-in-universal-analytics/

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Michele - this is great but doesn't quite answer the question about manually set _ga cookies.  I am going to give it a try on my local machine and see if it works.  Will report the outcome here.  I also have asked Simo.